# How do I strip accents from characters in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, unicode, character-encoding

I keep looking, but can't find an XSL function that is the equivalent of "normalize-space", for characters.  That is, my content has accented UNICODE characters, which is great, but from that content, I'm creating a filename, where I don't want those accents.

So, is there something that I'm overlooking, or not googling properly, to easily process characters?

In the XML data:

```
<filename>gri_gonéwiththèw00mitc</filename>
```

In XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:variable name="file">
    <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$file"/>
```

results in "gri_gonéwiththèw00mitc"

where

```
<xsl:value-of select='replace( normalize-unicode( "$file", "NFKD" ), "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "" )'/>
```

results in nothing.

What I'm aiming for is `gri_gonewiththew00mitc` (no accents)

Am I using the syntax wrong?

Comment: Removing accents only works for a small subset of Unicode characters. As far as I know, there's no standard way of latinized transcription of characters. (That is to say, there's a different one for each language.)

Comment: Check my answer for the correct RegExp syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In XSLT/XPath 1.0 if you want to replace those accented characters with the unaccented counterpart, you could use `translate()` function.

But, that assumes your "accented UNICODE characters" aren't composed unicode characters. If that were the case, you would need to use XPath 2.0 `normalize-unicode()` function.

And, if the real goal is to have a valid URI, you should use [`encode-for-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xpath-functions-20070123/#func-encode-for-uri)

**Update**: Examples

```
translate('gri_gonéwiththèw00mitc','áàâäéèêëíìîïóòôöúùûü','aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuu')
```

Result: `gri_gonewiththew00mitc`

```
encode-for-uri('gri_gonéwiththèw00mitc')
```

Result: `gri_gon%C3%A9withth%C3%A8w00mitc`

Correct expression provide suggest by @biziclop:

```
replace(normalize-unicode('gri_gonéwiththèw00mitc','NFKD'),'\P{ASCII}','')
```

Result: `gri_gonewiththew00mitc`

**Note**: In XPath 2.0, the correct character class negation is with a capital `\P`.

Comment: `translate()` assumes that you list all the characters you want to replace. My guess is that OP wants to avoid this. Although I don't think it's possible in general.

Comment: @biziclop: There is a reason for my answer having only one link to `encode-for-uri()` function.

Comment: @Alejandro On second thought, if you normalize your string to NFKD form and then throw away every non-basic ASCII (0-127) character (you can use a regexp replace for that), you will get an accent-free string.

Answer (score 3):

So, contrary to my comment, you could try this:

```
replace( normalize-unicode( "öt hűtőházból kértünk színhúst", "NFKD" ), "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "" )
```

Although be warned that any characters which can't be decomposed and aren't basic ASCII (Norwegian `ø` or Icelandic `Þ` for example) will be completely deleted from the string, but that's probably okay with your requirements.

Comment: Good example. Do check my update for the correct RegExp character class negation syntax.

Comment: Where is this RegExp syntax example?   I need to replace a list of characters.... `ɔ `ɛ and a few that I can`t even enter here....  As is noted these composed characters are deleted from the string using the above replace(normalize-unicode()) example. thx

Answer (score 2):

The previously suggested ways contain unknownthe  character class named 'ASCII'. In my experience, XPath 2.0 recognises the class 'BasicLatin', which should serve the same purpose as 'ASCII'.

```
replace(normalize-unicode('Lliç d'Am Oükl Úkřeč', 'NFKD'), '\P{IsBasicLatin}', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The top voted answer does not work anymore XPath2.0, as mentioned by Yuri. The 'IsBasicLatin' is an appropriate substitution for ASCII

The following code works:

```
replace(normalize-unicode('çgri_gonéwiththèmitç','NFKD'),'\P{IsBasicLatin}','')
```